# python split file into smaller chunks efficiently

Tags: python

In python, how could i split a file into smaller chunks efficiently?
for example, I have a file contains 140 lines. I want to split the file into file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt. file1 has 50 lines, file2 has 50 lines and file3 has the rest 40 lines.

Answer (score 5):

```
chunksize = 50
fid = 1
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    f = open('file%d.txt' %fid, 'w')
    for i,line in enumerate(infile):
        f.write(line)
        if not i%chunksize:
            f.close()
            fid += 1
            f = open('file%d.txt' %fid, 'w')
    f.close()
```